# Return in a function called by jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony-1.4

I've got a problem. I'm using Symfony 1.4 in my project, with a module module1 and a method executeAjaxEdit in the action.class.php. So in one of my templates I have this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "<?php echo url_for('module1/ajaxEdit')?>",
    data : {'data': mydata},
    async : false,
});
```

Is there a way to get back the result from my method executeAjaxEdit?

Thanks everyone (sorry for my English I'm a French student)

EDIT: I've found the problem, in my function executeAjaxEdit I had `return myReturn` instead of `echo myReturn` which is ok and send my data back to the ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then I think this should do it:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "<?php echo url_for('module1/ajaxEdit')?>",
    data : {'data': mydata},
    async : false,
    success: function (result){ /*result is result on success*/ },
    error: function (result) { /*result is result on error*/ }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I already tried to do "success: function (result){ alert(result);}", but the "alert popup" is always empty

Comment: That could be because your ajaxEdit function is returning an empty result. Try to inspect your ajax call  with, for example, chrome dev tools